# How to change a String into Variable in JavaScript like $$ does in PHP?

Tags: javascript

In PHP you can turn a string into a variable with $$variable.

I would like to change this javascript-code:

```
$( function () {
  $("a#toggleBoxes_B").toggle( function() {

    $("input[name=B0]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("input[name=B1]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("input[name=B2]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("input[name=B3]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("input[name=B4]").attr('checked', 'checked');
        ...
    $("input[name=B29]").attr('checked', 'checked');

    return false;
  }
});
```

INTO:

```
$( function () {
  $("a#toggleBoxes_B").toggle( function() {

    for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
             $("input[name=B[i]]").attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    return false;
  }
});
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: `$("input[name=B"+i+"]").attr('checked', 'checked');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with variables. It's all just strings.

You want simple string concatenation:

```
 $("input[name=B" + i + "]")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
 $("input[name=B" + i + "]").prop('checked', true);
```

Suggestion use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Use Javasxripts concatination sign (+) in order to parse your index:

```
$( function () {
  $("a#toggleBoxes_B").toggle( function() {

    for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
         $("input[name=B" + i + "]").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```